# What is the good practice to handle unrecognized custom HTTP headers?

Tags: api, http

Sometimes when custom headers (e.g. X-CUSTOM-HEADER:abc) are introduced, but it's not a required field of a request, should we throw an error or just ignore it? Is there any existing standard for this case?